# cannot create sub directories in Views for Code Igniter frame work

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory

i have a website i am running under CodeIgniter www.nationalpaymentcard.com

For awhile now i have ad the website running fine but have all my pages set up in the Views folder. I was trying to make a sub directory in there like Views/NewsPosts/post1.php to organize my files a little better but if i ever do that i get a 404.

Now i have been researching for awhile but i guess im not sure what exactly to google to figure out what i need to do. I was hoping someone out there on the internets could help point me the right way. Im thinking i may need to configure my controllers.php file but im not sure how... or if i need to add another one.

this is my current controllers.php

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {   
        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: do you move all the files from `Views` to `NewsPosts` or just the `home.php`?

Comment: No not all, im just trying to move certain pages to it

Comment: currently i have my templates and view folders, in view i have home and then id like to have a folder in View that holds other pages but those don't display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its look like your 'if' condition is not right, if you change the if it should work

```
if ( ! file_exists(VIEWPATH.'pages/'.$page.'.php'))
{
    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
    show_404();
}
```

Comment: would that allow me to access subdirectories?

Comment: This is just for not to get the 404 error as the condition was wrong.

Comment: You can set where ever you want on your view `$this->load->view('/YOURDIR/ANOTHERDIR/FILE', $data);`

Comment: OOOOHHHH so i just need to add another line like that to set the path to another directory. That way the system knows where to go if it ever gets called to go into a sub directory ya?

Comment: AKA:   $this->load->view('pages/NewsPosts/'.$page, $data);

Comment: Yes exactly, its just like a include, you need to tell the correct path

Comment: You can also over write the view loading functionality by extending the CI_Loader class if you need very custom modification

Comment: hmm im going to try the first method tonight and see how it goes, if not then ill get back to you on your latest suggestion lol :) Thanks Minhaz! ill be crossing my fingers, hoping this works!

Comment: Hey Minhaz, your suggestion worked! but now when i got to any page in the subdirectory my links on the footer and header attain the subdirectory infront of them so if the links were pointing to /home/ when you go to the sub directory the link says /subdirectory/home/ which is wrong. how do i make it so you can go back from the subdirectory?